# How to read zip file within a jar file

Tags: java

I have a zip file (within a jar file) which I want to read init.
I understand I can read easily the txt files using getResourceAsStream(...), avoiding the error "URI not hierarchical".
But now sure how would i do that for zip file.

Following is my code but it throws me "URI not hierachical error" when I export my code to runnable jar and run it.

```
URL fileLocation = ChemicalSynonyms.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sciome/workbench/resources/chemicalSynonym/" + strFileName);
        File file = new File(fileLocation.toURI());

        // it is a zip file
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String lineJustFetched = null;
        String[] wordsArray;

        // read each line
        lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: the first line. I know for txt file, it should be getresourceasstream instead of getresource, but dont know how would i deal with zip file

Comment: Can't you load stream of resource file and attach it to ZipFile class? Or maybe make temp file in file system and then load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using scanner. Example:

```
        InputStream is = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file location with zip file name);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(zis);

        String[] wordsArray;
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
           ....
        }
```